# Why do I get "Module not found" error related to favicon.ico when starting a new Next.js 14 app using create-next-app?

Tags: next.js, next.js13, next.js14

I ran the following command to start a new Next.js app:

```
npx create-next-app@latest
```

But `npm run dev` gives me the following error:

```
Module not found: Can't resolve 'C:\xxxxx\xxxxx\xxxxx\my-app\src\app\favicon.ico?__next_metadata__'
```

What is strange is that, actually, 5% of the time I run `npm run dev`, I don't get this error.

Is this some kind of bug related to Next.js version `14.0.3`? I have no such error when using Next.js 13.

I found [this](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/48603) issue on GitHub, especially [this](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/48603#issuecomment-1520273796) comment, which sounds like it could solve my problem since I'm on Windows, but I don't find the `get-metadata-route.ts` file. Perhaps it is renamed in Next.js 14?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but I resolved it by moving the project to my desktop and it started working and I think that was just a problem with Windows path type "/" "\".